# MYSQL Create a Pivot Values to Column Group By

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

**My original table:**

| ID | DATE | CITY | STRING | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/4/2021 | NEW YORK | A | DONE |
| 1 | 3/4/2021 | NEW YORK | B | PENDING |
| 2 | 3/4/2021 | CHICAGO | A | DONE |
| 2 | 3/4/2021 | CHICAGO | B | DONE |
| 3 | 3/4/2021 | ATLANTA | A | PENDING |
| 3 | 3/4/2021 | ATLANTA | B | PENDING |

**My Code:**

```
SELECT ID, DATE, STRING, VALUE,

    IF(STRING = 'A', VALUE, NULL) AS 'A',
    IF(STRING = 'B', VALUE, NULL) AS 'B'
    
FROM Records GROUP BY ID, DATE
```

**Result:**

| ID | DATE | CITY | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/4/2021 | NEW YORK | **DONE** | NULL |
| 1 | 3/4/2021 | NEW YORK | NULL | **PENDING** |
| 2 | 3/4/2021 | CHICAGO | **DONE** | NULL |
| 2 | 3/4/2021 | CHICAGO | NULL | **DONE** |
| 3 | 3/4/2021 | ATLANTA | **PENDING** | NULL |
| 3 | 3/4/2021 | ATLANTA | NULL | **PENDING** |

**Expectative:**

| ID | DATE | CITY | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/4/2021 | NEW YORK | DONE | PENDING |
| 2 | 3/4/2021 | CHICAGO | DONE | DONE |
| 3 | 3/4/2021 | ATLANTA | PENDING | PENDING |

Thanks for your support

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to use `conditional aggregation` by adding `max` around your `if` statement:

```
SELECT ID, DATE, CITY,
    MAX(IF(STRING = 'A', VALUE, NULL)) AS 'A',
    MAX(IF(STRING = 'B', VALUE, NULL)) AS 'B'
FROM Records 
GROUP BY ID, DATE, CITY
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding two columns `A` and `B`, and not adding them to the aggregation function

PD: Also, please as @strawberry said, add the necessary code to reproduce it (Create tables, inserts, and any other thing needed)